# I have written a regex for matching the sub string with spaces around it but that's not working well

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds, substitution

Actually I was working on a regex problem whose task is to take a substring (||, &&) and replaces it with another substring (or, and) and I wrote  code for it but that's not working well

```
question = x&& &&& && && x || | ||\|| x
Expected output = x&& &&& and and x or | ||\|| x
```

Here is the code I wrote

```
import re
for i in range(int(input())):
    print(re.sub(r'\s[&]{2}\s', ' and ', re.sub(r"\s[\|]{2}\s", " or ", input())))
```

My output = x&& &&& and && x or | ||\|| x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use lookarounds, the problem with the current regex is `&& &&` here the `&&` the first match captures the space so there's no space available before the second `&&` and it won't match, so we need to use `zero-length-match ( lookarounds)`

Replace the regex

```
\s[&]{2}\s  -->  (?<=\s)[&]{2}(?=\s)
\s[\|]{2}\s -->    (?<=\s)[\|]{2}(?=\s)
```

---

`(?<=\s)` - Match should be precede space characters

`(?=\s)` - Match should be followed by space characters

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a regex like `(?<=\s)&&(?=\s)` [(Regex demo)](https://regex101.com/r/szhE9H/1/)

Using lookarounds to assert the position of space characters around your targeted replacement groups allows overlapping matches to occur - otherwise, it will match the spaces on both sides and block out the other options.

```py
import re

in_str = 'x&& &&& && && x || | ||\|| x'
expect_str = 'x&& &&& and and x or | ||\|| x'

print(re.sub("(?<=\s)\|\|(?=\s)", "or", re.sub("(?<=\s)&&(?=\s)", "and", in_str)))
```

[Python demo](https://repl.it/repls/FractalWhichSubversion)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `re.findall()` instead of `re.sub`